# Efficient way to add to JS objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to add a bunch of attributes to an object, each of which is an empty array. My implementation seems verbose.

```
let obj = {};
obj.x = [];
obj.y = [];
obj.z = [];
```

... ad infinitum

Is there any other way, like reverse object de-structuring?

Comment: wich name should have your empty array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let obj = {};

for(let key of "xyz")
    obj[key] = []

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Great. Would you recommend `const` or `let` ?
btw for anyone else this is what I ended up with:
`for ( let key of ['key1','key2','key3'] )`
`{ obj[key] = [] }`
So I get: 
`obj = { key1: [], key2: [], key3: [] }`

Comment: const if the variable should never be overwritten, let otherwise

Comment: `const` and `let` are about reference not value so `const obj = {}; obj.thing = 'thing';` is fine while `const obj = {}; obj = {thing: 'thing'};` will error.

Answer (score 3):

you can try

```
var obj = {};
var keys = [ "x", "y", "z" ];
keys.forEach( function( val ){ 
  obj[ val ] = []; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of doing it in one line

```
var obj = ['x', 'y', 'z'].reduce((obj, key) => (obj[key] = [], obj), {})
```

Then it can be reusable

```js
var fn = (obj, key) => (obj[key] = [], obj);
var dest = {};

var same = ['x', 'y', 'z'].reduce(fn, dest)

console.log(dest)
console.log(same === dest)
```